# How to align image avec text in two lines, which works in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I try to align an image (a logo) with a text in two lines (the title of the website and a short description).

I try to do this HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr-FR" lang="fr-FR">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="site">
            <div id="header">
                <a title="Retour à l'accueil" href="#"><img width="40" height="40" title="mon logo" alt="mon logo" src="images/logo.png"/></a>
                <div class="title">
                    <h1>Mon site</h1>
                    <div>mon sous-titre avec des g et des p</div>
                </div>
                <div class="switchlanguage right">
                    <a href="#" title="english site"><strong>english</strong></a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <p>homepage</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

with this style.css :

```
/**********
 * RESET *
 **********/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
/*table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,*/
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
html {
    overflow:auto;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;/*#656565;*/
}
ol, ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

 /**********
 * COMMON *
 **********/
body {
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#333333;
}

.left {
    float:left;
}
.right {
    float:right;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
    height:0;
}
#site strong {
    font-weight:700;
}
#header, #content, #footer {
    width: 990px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

 /**********
 * HEADER *
 **********/

 #header {
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
 }

 #header img {
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border: none;
 }

 #header div.title {
    float: left;
    padding-left:20px;
 }

 #header div.title h1 {
    font-size:2.6em;
    line-height:0.904em;
    height:0.904em;
 }

 #header div.title div {
    font-size:1.8em;
    line-height:0.917em;    
    height:1em;
 }
 #header .switchlanguage {
    font-size:1.1em;
 }
 #header .switchlanguage a {
    background-image:url('images/icn_langage.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left center;
    padding-left:20px;
    color:#333333;
    text-decoration:none;
 }
 /**********
 * CONTENT *
 **********/

 #content {
    background-image:url('images/bg_body_repeat.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    min-height:400px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #909090;
 }
```

But in IE7, the letters p and g is cropped.

[You can see the result here](http://www.cedricescarment.com/template)

What is the best practice to align image and a text in two lines ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css here:

```
#header div.title div {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 0.917em;
    height: 1em;
}
```

Increase your `line-height` - this should fix it. The exact value will require some testing and depend on your design.

You might also, want to wrap your text in `<p>` tags instead of `<div>` tags, as you did somewhere else in the code - just for semantics!

Answer (score 0):

Change HTML to

```
            <div class="title">
                <h1>Mon site</h1>
                <div class="tagline">mon sous-titre avec des g et des p</div>
            </div>
```

and CSS to

```
.title .tagline{
   padding:0 0 2px 0;
}
```

if you know that you are ever going to have 1 div inside the title div, you can change the style to

```
.title div{ padding:0 0 2px 0;}
```

and not do a separate class(.tagline) like above